# Vuex - parameter passed to action gets lost. Replaced with current state

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

So on a button click I want to create an object and pass it to my action.
Unfortunately, even the test variable isn't working.
Calling the action within a component:

```
submitFeedback(){
  var jsonMessage = 'test message'
  console.log('test in menu: '+ jsonMessage)
  this [UC.SET_USER_FEEDBACK](jsonMessage)
  console.log('message sent')
}
```

Executing the action:

```
 async [UC.SET_USER_FEEDBACK](feedbackFormData) {
    console.log('test in action:' + feedbackFormData)    
}
```

Result in Console:

```
test in menu: test message
test in action:[object Object]
message sent
```

Is the component perhaps outside the scope of Vuex?  It has mapGetters, mapActions and mapState from vuex available.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of vuex action is context.
You should pass extra data as the second parameter.

```
async [UC.SET_USER_FEEDBACK](context, feedbackFormData) {
    console.log('test in action:' + feedbackFormData)    
}
```